# Adding 2 values to parameter when databinding using DataList in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datalist

I have the code

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" 
       DataKeyField="TextId" OnEditCommand="DataList1_EditCommand"
       OnCancelCommand="DataList1_CancelCommand" 
       OnDeleteCommand="DataList1_DeleteCommand" 
       OnUpdateCommand="DataList1_UpdateCommand">
     <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="TheNotes"
             Text='<%# Bind("notes") %>' />
     </EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
```

What i want to do is bind 2 variables to one control

```
  <asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="TheNotes"
     Text='<%# Bind("notes") Bind("dates")  %>' />
```

Anyone know how to do this ? without it erroring, they are both in the control datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can do it by using the below 3 solutions

**Solution 1 :**

```
<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="TheNotes"
     Text='<%# Bind("notes") + Bind("dates")  %>' />
```

**Solution 2 :**

You can do one more things, u can select two column as a single column in sql select query.

```
SELECT (ColumnA + ColumnB) AS ColumnZ
FROM Table;
```

and then bind it with single control

**Solution 3:**

[bind multiple data to itemtemplate in gridview using Row data bound](http://forums.asp.net/t/1782385.aspx)

And

[using string format](http://forums.asp.net/post/5077167.aspx)